# Filtering the fields listed by the CreateModelMixin based on ForeignKey in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-rest-viewsets

**Hello, I am starting to learn Django Rest Framework, i have come across a problem, that i couldn't solve, that is described below:**

**I have defined three models in models.py:**

Endpoint Model

```
class Endpoint(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

MLAlgorithm model:

```
class MLAlgorithm(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    parent_endpoint = models.ForeignKey('Endpoint', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="mlalgorithms")

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

ABTest model:

```
class ABTest(models.Model):
    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    parent_endpoint = models.ForeignKey('Endpoint', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="abtests")
    parent_mlalgorithm_1 = models.ForeignKey('MLAlgorithm', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="parent_mlalgorithm_1")
    parent_mlalgorithm_2 = models.ForeignKey('MLAlgorithm', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="parent_mlalgorithm_2")

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title
```

**and defined their serializers:**

Endpoint Serializer:

```
class EndpointSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Endpoint
        read_only_fields = ("id", "name", "created_by", "created_at")
        fields = read_only_fields
```

MLAlgorithm Serializer:

```
class MLAlgorithmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MLAlgorithm
        read_only_fields = (
            "id", "name", "created_by", "created_at", "parent_endpoint")
        fields = read_only_fields
```

ABTest Serializer:

```
class ABTestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ABTest
        read_only_fields = ("id", "created_at")
        fields = (
            "id", "title", "created_by", "created_at", "parent_endpoint", "parent_mlalgorithm_1", "parent_mlalgorithm_2")
```

Then i created a viewset for the ABTest:

```
class ABTestViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin):

    serializer_class = ABTestSerializer
    queryset = ABTest.objects.all()
```

My problem is in the ABTestView:

for example, i have created two endpoints, and each endpoint has two algorithms:

```
endpoint_1:
    algorithm_1
    algorithm_2

endpoint_2:
    algorithm_3
    algorithm_4
```

but when i select a specific endpoint in the view, i want only the specific algorithms to be shown not all the algorithms available in the database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBtpk.png)

i don't know how to force algorithm filtering in the view, should i filter the algorithms by their endpoints in the view or before serialization, unfortunately i am struggling to implement it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm glad I found this question because I'm struggling with the same kind of problem right now. The use of reverse ForeignKeys seems to be a special issue here. Have you ever been able to solve this problem and if so, do you eventually have a hint for me? Thanks.